# Nesting the IF Function in Excel when there may be #Value! errors in the target cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get some help to change a formula:

`=IF(S4>8000,3,IF(S4>6000,2,IF(S4>4000,1,IF(S4<4000,0))))`

So that it returns a value of 1.5 if the target cell contains an error value.  Would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: You'll want to use the "IFERROR" formula. I'm not at my computer at the moment but I'll update with more details later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`IFERROR`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/iferror-function-HA010342587.aspx) function allows you to check for an error and return a value if true.

> Returns a value you specify if a formula evaluates to an error;
>   otherwise, returns the result of the formula. Use the IFERROR function
>   to trap and handle errors in a formula.

The syntax for this is `IFERROR(value, value_if_error)`

Therefore, you can nest your existing formula within the `IFERROR`, as the `value` in the syntax above. This will capture the error.

```
=IFERROR(IF(S4>8000,3,IF(S4>6000,2,IF(S4>4000,1,IF(S4<4000,0,IF(ISERROR(S4),1.5))))), 1.5)
```